# Missing assembly in Visual Studio 2012 ( but it is there! Honest! )

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly, reactiveui

I have a project using Reactive Extensions and ReactiveUI. I upgraded to the pre release version and I have the following line of code

```
    OAPHCreationHelperMixin.ObservableToProperty(observable,
                                                 Function(x) x.Value
```

Visual studio tells me there is an error here on the method ObservableToPropertyin that the following assembly is missing

```
    Error   9       
    C:\Users\phelan\workspace\WeinMeasEval\WeinMeasEval\Global\ObservableBinding.vb 
    Reference required to assembly 
    'System.Reactive.Interfaces, 
    Version=2.0.20823.0, 
    Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
    containing the type 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler'. Add one to your project.
```

Now I click the link which suggests it will add the reference and then nothing
happens. If I look in my project references I see that the assembly is indeed
in the assembly list and it is the correct version 2.0.20823.0 and if I look on
the path the DLL is indeed there.

Any ideas?

Comment: `[visual-studio-2011]` should be a synonym for `[visual-studio-2012]` - someone with enough reputation should suggest that :-)

Comment: I changed the tag to visual-studio-2012 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed, check out ReactiveUI 4.0 Preview 5

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that at **this date** reactive UI is not built yet for .NET 4.5 as the developer is having some build issues.

As a work around I build it myself by pulling the repository from Git and referring to the core library directly from within my .NET 4.5 project.

This seems to work at the moment. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Target Framework set to full .net or to Client Profile (in project settings)?

Comment: .NET 4.5 (full) there seems to be no option for client profile for 4.5

Comment: Which is correct as it has been discontinued. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx